# Assign multiple feature group in edit control in leaflet draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

How can i assign multiple the feature groups in edit control,

> Assume we have two feature groups(It can be multiple),and we want to assign edit control to both groups.

This is groups,

```
var attLayerGroup = new L.FeatureGroup();
var photoLayerGroup = new L.FeatureGroup();
```

And this is, How i assign control to groups,

```
    var drawControl = map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: photoLayerGroup,attLayerGroup,
        poly: {
            allowIntersection: true
        }
    },
    draw: {
        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false,
            showArea: true
        }

    }
}));
```

> Is it right way to assigning Edit control to FeatureGroup ?
>   If not,How can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific distinction between your 2 initial Feature Groups, then simply copy the reference of each individual layer into a new parent Feature Group and use the latter as Leaflet.draw `featureGroup` option:

```js
var fg = L.featureGroup();

photoLayerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  if (!layer instanceof L.LayerGroup) {
    fg.addLayer(layer);
  }
});

// Same for attLayerGroup.

new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: fg
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Leaflet.Draw `featureGroup` does not accept multiple feature groups.

You can have two instances of Leaflet.Draw set up, one for each feature group. However, I predict you will have issues with the buttons Leaflet.Draw sets up and possibly the events thrown by each instance.

The second option is to have a single instances of Leaflet.Draw and you swap the feature group with a toggle.